# Symfony2 Doctrine2 get result using criteria with second relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to ask Is there any simple method to get data with conditions in second relation.

In my controller I get every category entity.

Every category have many products so there is relation "OneToMany".
Next every product have an author and there is relation "ManyToOne".

Now I would like to get every category which include products whose are active and whose author is active.

category OneToMany product
product ManyToOne author
product have field "active"
author have field "active"

My method to get products in Category entity.

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('isVisible', true));
    $criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('isActive', true));
    
    return $this->products->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Hello? I see you asked a lot of question, but hardly ever accepted an answer. It's a bit rude to ask for help and ignoring people investing time in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `getProducts()`, Doctrine gets all entries from the database and selects products matching your criteria. While this works for now, it's better to use your database (MySQL?) to select the right entries.

So use a QueryBuilder instead. And since you're Symfony, create those methods in a [Repository](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/repository.html).

We're not here to write your code, but to give you an idea, it can be something like this:

> CategoryRepository.php

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

class CategoryRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Category::class);
    }

    public function findActiveCategories()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('Category')
            ->innerJoin(
                'AppBundle:Product',
                'Product',
                Join::WITH,
                'Category.id = Product.category'
            )
            ->where('Product.isActive = 1')
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```